# How to Sum all working days for each month but restart from 0 for every month in power Bi Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to know how could I get the Sum of all working days for specific month but in the table starting each month's Sum over again.

This is my DateTable Now with this query for Work Days Sum:

```
Work Days Sum = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'DateTable'[Is working Day] ),
    ALL ( 'DateTable' ),
    'DateTable'[Date] <= EARLIER ( 'DateTable'[Date] )
)
```

```
Date         |  Month Order | Is working day |  Work Days Sum  | 
January              -              21                 331
2022/01/01   |       1      |        0       |                 |
2022/01/02   |       1      |        0       |                 |
2022/01/03   |       1      |        1       |         1       |
2022/01/04   |       1      |        1       |         2       |
2022/01/05   |       1      |        1       |         3       |
2022/01/06   |       1      |        1       |         4       |
.....
2022/01/27   |       1      |        1       |         19      |
2022/01/28   |       1      |        1       |         20      |
2022/01/29   |       1      |        0       |         20      |
2022/01/30   |       1      |        0       |         20      |
2022/01/31   |       1      |        1       |         21      |
          
February                             20                890
2022/02/01   |       2      |        1       |         22      |
2022/02/02   |       2      |        1       |         23      |
2022/02/03   |       2      |        1       |         24      |
2022/02/04   |       2      |        1       |         25      |



                                    |
                                    |
                                    V

Date         |  Month Order | Is working day |  Work Days Sum  | 
January              -              21                 21
2022/01/01   |       1      |        0       |                 |
2022/01/02   |       1      |        0       |                 |
2022/01/03   |       1      |        1       |         1       |
2022/01/04   |       1      |        1       |         2       |
2022/01/05   |       1      |        1       |         3       |
2022/01/06   |       1      |        1       |         4       |
.....
2022/01/27   |       1      |        1       |         19      |
2022/01/28   |       1      |        1       |         20      |
2022/01/29   |       1      |        0       |         20      |
2022/01/30   |       1      |        0       |         20      |
2022/01/31   |       1      |        1       |         21      |
          
February                             20                41
2022/02/01   |       2      |        1       |         1       |
2022/02/02   |       2      |        1       |         2       |
2022/02/03   |       2      |        1       |         3       |
2022/02/04   |       2      |        1       |         4       |
2022/02/05   |       2      |        0       |         4       |
.....
```

Any idea on how I can change my dax query to achieve output of second table below the down arrow would be much appreciated.